# Inner class cannot see the definition of another inner class with Python Ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I tried converting C code snippet to Python by using Ctypes, but it doesn't work. The C code is as below:

```c
struct A
{
    struct B
    {
        // Empty
    };

    struct C
    {
        B b;
    };
};
```

My Python code is:

```py
from ctypes import Structure

class A(Structure):
    class B(Structure):
        _fields_ = []

    class C(Structure):
        _fields_ = [("b", A.B)]   # Error: Unresolved reference 'A'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to *interface* with C code? Or are you writing new code entirely in Python?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Interface with C code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python, a class is bound to its name after the entire class has been defined. `A` does not exist for the duration of the definition. The `ctypes` [Structures and unions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) shows how to construct nested structures. Each is defined as an outer class separately and its the `Structure._fields_` attribute that makes one subordinate to the other.

```
from ctypes import Structure

class B(Structure):
    _fields_ = []

class C(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("b", B)]

class A(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("B", B), ("C", C)]
```